# springboot @PostConstruct methods are called twice

Tags: spring-boot

I've noticed that my beans invoke `@PostConstruct`'s `init()` and `@Scheduled` twice one time on spring-boot application in jar. Here's sample bean that got initialized twice.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "task")
public class CancelTask {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CancelTask.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("CancelTask init:{}", this);
        printStackTrace();
    }

    private void printStackTrace() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackElements = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (stackElements != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < stackElements.length; i++) {
                sb.append("" + stackElements[i] + "\n");
            }
        }
        log.info(sb.toString());
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
    public void closeTask() {
        log.info("close task start....{}", this);
        printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`@PostConstruct` and `@Scheduled` were called twice:

From log,PostConstruct was first called:

```
[INFO] [2017-12-20 19:54:29,872] [c.n.m.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask]: CancelTask init:com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask@34451ed8
[INFO] [2017-12-20 19:54:29,873] [c.n.m.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask]: com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask.printStackTrace(CancelTask.java:85)
com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask.init(CancelTask.java:81)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
com.netease.mail.workbench.Application.main(Application.java:61)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

second was called:

```
[INFO] [2017-12-20 19:54:36,148] [c.n.m.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask]: CancelTask init:com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask@34451ed8
[INFO] [2017-12-20 19:54:36,150] [c.n.m.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask]: com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask.printStackTrace(CancelTask.java:85)
com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask.init(CancelTask.java:81)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:400)
org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.rebind(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:107)
org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.rebind(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:90)
org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.onApplicationEvent(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:138)
org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.onApplicationEvent(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.java:51)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.java:79)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
com.netease.mail.workbench.Application.main(Application.java:61)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

and @Scheduled was called twice one time:

```
[INFO] [2017-12-20 19:57:00,006] [c.n.m.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask]: close task start....com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask@34451ed8
[INFO] [2017-12-20 19:57:00,006] [c.n.m.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask]: close task start....com.netease.mail.workbench.daemon.task.CancelTask@34451ed8
```

when I removed `@ConfigurationProperties` , `@PostConstruct` and `@Scheduled` was called only once. And I'm very sure the `CancelTask`class  has only one instance.

Comment: I think your issue is described in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2186

Comment: Yeah, and I reopen issue in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11384 .But was closed by  bclozel,he thought it  was not a issue.

Comment: And this problem is closed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163080/spring-boot-scheduled-task-double-invocation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not related to Spring Cloud at all (some comments are suggesting that), as I can reproduce this behaviour without it.

This happens because you're creating two beans for `CancelTask`. One is created by `@Component` (+ scanned by `@ComponentScan`), another one is created because of `@ConfigurationProperties` (+ enabled with `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CancelTask.class)`).

If I run the same example locally, I get different instance IDs:

```
com.example.demo.CancelTask: CancelTask init:com.example.demo.SomethingProperties@273f65d9
com.example.demo.CancelTask: CancelTask init:com.example.demo.SomethingProperties@6066ff52
```

You're not supposed to mix application features and configuration infrastructure in single Spring component. You should cut this component into two; rule of thumb: if you can't name your configuration properties class `SomethingProperties`, then it's probably doing more than it's supposed to do.

Since configuration properties are beans, you can inject those in any other component.

Comment: Yeah,I use `@EnableConfigurationProperties`,it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, upvote Brian-Clozel answer.

My permutation was:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
public final class MyThing { 

    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    public void myMethod() {

    }
}
```

"myMethod" was running twice.

As per suggestion.. it was because I had it as a @Component AND @PostConstruct.

Removing the @Component resolved my issue.

```
public final class MyThing { 

    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    public void myMethod() {

    }
}
```